# How to align the icons in the same line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align the icons in the same line but they are not properly aligned.

Here is my code and screenshot is attached:

```
<div align="center">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
    <a href="" target="blank"><img src="images/googleplus.png"></a></li>            
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: here is the code: -

<div align="center">

   <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
   <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
   <a href="" target="blank"><img src="images/googleplus.png"></a></li>
   
</div>

Comment: why do you have list item closing tags `</li>` ??

Comment: Do the three `.png` files all have the same dimensions?

Comment: Why those `</li>` tags? Try removing it. If that doesn't solve, it might be the case that all `images` are of different sizes. In that case you can explicitly provide `height` & `width` to all the `images`.

Comment: Well if you validate your code, you will have errors. Make your HTML Valid.

Answer (score 3):

Centering item using flexbox.

```
<div class="center">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
    <a href="" target="blank"><img src="images/googleplus.png"></a>         
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.center a {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

As per chharvey comment. This is the way you can use ul li technique.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" target="blank"><img src="images/googleplus.png"></a>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li a img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Note: the flex in anchor tag is for the image to be aligned center. You might

Comment: best answer so far, but I would have liked to see a `<ul>` and `<li>` structure instead of just plain links in a div. And +1 for using flexbox :)

Comment: looks good, but you don't need any flex properties in the `ul li a`, because the list items already serve as the flex items. the links inside are just along for the ride.

Answer (score 0):

You don't open ul and li. You only close li tag.
If you wanna use li, you can see this solution:

**HTML:**

```
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/48/social-facebook-box-blue-icon.png" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yootheme/social-bookmark/48/social-twitter-box-blue-icon.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="blank"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/marcus-roberto/google-play/48/Google-plus-icon.png" alt="GooglePlus" title="GooglePlus"></a></li>  
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.icons{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.icons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Working example [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsJoe/hLeeyfhv/1/).

Comment: I like your list structure, but you shouldn't use the `align` attribute on divs in HTML5. Try using css for that instead.

Comment: @chharvey Done. Thank you.